# using angularjs to fetch data doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to develop a simple web application using `angularjs` i have a table `city` that is created using entityframework `database first`.

I added angularjs nuget to my project.and create 2 files in my project named `service` and `controller` as you can see here :

controller

```
MyApp.controller('UpdateController', function ($scope, CityService) {

    getCities();

    function getCities() {

        CityService.getCities()

            .success(function (cities) {

                $scope.cities = cities;

            })

            .error(function (error) {

                $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;

            });

    }

});
```

Service :

```
MyApp.factory('CityService', ['$http', function ($http) 
{
    var urlBase = 'http://localhost:37404/api';

    var CityService = {};

    CityService.getCities = function () {

        return $http.get(urlBase + '/default1');

    };

    return CityService;

}]);
```

I pass the data using webapi as you can see :

```
namespace MvcApplication8.Controllers
{
    public class Default1Controller : ApiController
    {
        private testDBEntities db = new testDBEntities();

        // GET: api/ManageStudentsInfoAPI  
        public IQueryable<City> GetStudent()
        {
            return db.Cities;
        }   
    }
}
```

Here is my view :

```
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p class="site-title">
                <a href="~/">ASP.NET Web API</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyAngularFile/Service.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyAngularFile/Controller.js"></script>
</header>
<div id="body">
    <div ng-controller="UpdateController">    
        <table class="table">    
            <tr> 

                <th>Id</th>

                <th>Name</th>

                <th>Country</th>

            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="a in cities">

                <td>{{a.Id}}</td>

                <td>{{a.Name}}</td>

                <td>{{a.Country}}</td>

           </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the result is like this :

[image]

My browser errors:

[image]

Comment: Is `ng-app` specified in the html code? Are there any errors in the browser console (Ctrl+shift+i to bring it up)?

Comment: @Petter i don't have any tag in my html code named ng-app .i added the error list to my post

Comment: Ok, you need an `ng-app="MyApp"` attribute, for example in the body tag. Also, the browser console complains that MyApp hasn't been defined. You probably need to add `var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp',  []);` in the Service.js file.

Comment: You could check a sample plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/FcgUs3NMTa6lsNDLLhKR?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
```

Then, in html:

```
<div id="body" ng-app="MyApp">
```

Comment: i get this error :Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=MyApp

Comment: Where should i add this line var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

Comment: before your controller/service implementation

Comment: can i add the var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp',[]); in another javascript file named module ?

Comment: Try adding a script app.js with contents var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);. Then, in both Service.js and Controller.js, add this on top of the script: var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp');